# How do I redirect one domain to another with Google Cloud DNS?

Tags: apache, google-cloud-platform, certbot, google-cloud-dns

I am hosting a couple websites with Apache on a Linux box on Google Cloud Compute.

For this specific domain, I want to use the *.co as the primary, but I also bought the *.com so that nobody can impersonate this domain. I want to send all traffic ( `http://*.com/` ; `http://www.*.com/` ; `https://*.com/` ; and `https://www.*.com/` ) from the *.com to the *.co .

I have created a folder in `/var/www` on the server for the *.co website.

```
cd /var/www
ls
*.co
```

Then I created configuration files for both domains in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` .

`*.co.conf` =

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin _____@_____.com
    ServerName *.co
    ServerAlias www.*.co
    DocumentRoot /var/www/*.co
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Setting a `301` redirect for the `*.com` domain.

`*.com.conf` =

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.com
    ServerAlias www.*.com
    Redirect 301 / http://*.co/
</VirtualHost>
```

After that, I enabled the configuration files with the Apache command `a2ensite` and restart the Apache service.

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
sudo a2ensite *.co.conf, *.com.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Then I log in to [Google Cloud DNS](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns/zones?) to create a *zone* for the `*.co` domain. There is already `SOA` and `NS` records created by default. I also logged in to [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/) to set *Custom name servers* for the domain and make sure that the four name server addresses match what is in the `NS` record in Google Cloud.

```
ns-cloud-x1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-x2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-x3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-x4.googledomains.com
```

I created an `A` record that points to the External IP of the server listed in [Google Cloud Compute Engine](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances?) and a `CNAME` record as well in [Google Cloud DNS](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns/zones?) so that the `www` points to the same address.

Then I did the same steps for the `*.com` site, updating the name server addresses in [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/) to match the `NS` record in [Google Cloud DNS](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-services/dns/zones?) and creating `A` and `CNAME` records.

At this point the `HTTP` site is up and running. I am trying to use Python 3 `certbot` for Apache on Ubuntu to generate `SSL` certificates to encrypt `HTTPS`. I believe `certbot` also adds some lines to the configuration file.

```
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-apache
```

I configured HTTPS on the `*.co` site with `certbot` and it seems to be working fine.

```
sudo certbot --apache -d *.co -v
```

...but then when I try to do the same with the *.com site, it doesn't work.

```
sudo certbot --apache -d *.com -v
```

I get a `Server Not Found` error in the browser.

```
Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site.

We can’t connect to the server at *.co.

If you entered the right address, you can:
    Try again later
    Check your network connection
    Check that Firefox has permission to access the web (you might be connected but behind a firewall)
```

What did I do wrong? Do I need to change one of the `DNS` records or something in the configuration files? Does the Python 3 `certbot` support `HTTPS` redirects?

Comment: UPDATE= I found a small spelling error in the configuration file for the `*.com` site. I missed a letter in the `Redirect 301 / http://*.co/` line. I corrected the error, restarted Apache, ran certbot again, and now I might have to wait for the `DNS` to proliferate throughout the internet...

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Do not use 301 redirects when testing. 2) Start testing in `incognito` windows. 3) certbot supports wildcard certificates with DNS challenges. Your command will not work. 4) Certbot does not wait for DNS to propagate. If it reports a problem, you still have one but first, you need to modify the certbot command.